# How to download image from Python CGI

Tags: python, cgi

I want to download image from Python CGI.

For example, I post img's base64 to CGI, and CGI output image.

I write this code.

Please advise me.

Python cgi side code

```
import cgi
import base64

query = cgi.FieldStorage()
img_list = query.getvalue("image").split(',')
contentType = img_list[0] #data:image/jpeg;base64 
base_64 = img_list[1]

print("Content-type: image/jpeg")
print(base64.b64decode(base_64))
```

Comment: You at least need a blank line between the headers and the content. Of course, writing CGI in 2014 is just masochistic; use a WSGI framework.

Comment: I know I had better use a WSGI framework. But I think no problem for this.because it is small.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try:

```
print("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
```

This means that it is raw bytes and can not be interpreted as anything useful by the browser.
The browser should then open a download dialog.

Comment: The browser open a download dialog, but it download test.py. test.py is python file on cgi.

Comment: I want to download image

Comment: Then either make that the python file is executed or make that the python file prints an image instead of itself.